# sqlcmd not returning error

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, sql-server-2012, powershell-3.0

I am running the following sqlcmd via power shell

```
$dump = sqlcmd -S $server -Q $sqlCommand -t $queryTimeout -b -h -1 -W
```

I trying the write the output to screen

```
$message = "Error while executing sql {0}, Error details {1}" -f "$sqlCommand","$dump" 
Write-Warning $message
```

but `$dump` is empty

Comment: Are you expecting $dump to contain an error? $dump would only contain data send to the output stream. If its from the error stream you need to redirect that `$dump = sqlcmd -S $server -Q $sqlCommand -t $queryTimeout -b -h -1 -W 2>&1`... maybe

Comment: SQLCMD is a weird creature. I would confirm by running the query in SQL and checking you do actually get a result, then mess with the switches. I tend to run full scripts so I use `-i` and give a filename, but I could only get it working with `& (SQLCMD) -s localhost -x -i $file`. Try removing all your switches, and if you get a result start adding them back.

Comment: I expect dump to contain the output of the sql file , as if i ran it in SQL management studio

Comment: @Matt the example you gave worked , thanks please make it an answer  . What is 2>&1 used for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `sqlcmd.exe` but from the description of your expectations I think that sqlcmd is sending information down the error stream. This is a seemingly odd but common practice and therefore occurrence.

Problem here is that the variable `$dump` will only collect information send to the output stream. What you can do is redirect the error stream to output stream with a redirector. For more information you can look at [about_redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

So using the following will accomplish that:

```
$dump = sqlcmd -S $server -Q $sqlCommand -t $queryTimeout -b -h -1 -W 2>&1
```

The linked document describes `2>&1` as

> Sends errors (2) and success output (1) to the success output stream.

Now `$dump` should contain what you are looking for. Be careful though as it might contain more information than you expect.